# gtk.PrintOperation reset status?

Tags: gtk, pygtk

Is it possible to reset status of printing somehow, or is it always necessary to create new PrintOperation? For example, if you show printPreview, it is necessary to recreate PrintOperation before calling it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is... PrintOperation is invalidated after finishing, so it has to be recreated for actual printing ie.